# DragAndDrop unable to change the order of gridview row using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am using gridView which is movable with dragAndDrop its working to move rows but unable to change the order of rows. This is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="0"  OnRowDataBound="GridView2_RowDataBound" ForeColor="#333" runat="server">               
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#989898" ForeColor="white" />
</asp:GridView>
// js for dragAndDrop
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id*=GridView2]").sortable({
            items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
            cursor: 'pointer',
            axis: 'y',
            dropOnEmpty: false,
            start: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.addClass("selected");
            },
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                ui.item.removeClass("selected");
            },
            receive: function (e, ui) {
                $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
            }
        });
    });
</Script>
```

Tell me where i am wrong or what i need to change the order of gridView rows.

Comment: you need to enable drag and drop on the gridview

Comment: You may consider switch to MVC if you have complicated front-end operation

Comment: @PPann using  these (AllowDrop="True" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" ), still not working

Comment: does your cursor change when you start to drag? I'm not having asp.net on my PC so I can't fix the code on the fly but we will get you sorted, no worries. without the grid using jquery there are a lot of updates but I guess you need to update back to the db right? https://blog.stackhive.com/post/137799349684/building-a-seamless-drag-and-drop-interface

Comment: I am not seeing this solved without jscript with I do. https://www.aspforums.net/Threads/963916/Drag-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-another-and-save-in-Database-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet/